# Existence of Phase Flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi there I'm wondering if anyone can clear up my confusion:  What is the proof of the local existence of a phase flow for a differentiable vector field?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $X^i:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ are $n$ coordinates of a vector field. We seek a set of functions $\phi^i(x_0,t)$ for small $t$ such that $\partial \phi^i\partial t =X^i(\phi(x_0,t))$.

By even just the Peano existence theorem (multidimensional version), we find such a $\phi$ exists by continuity of $X$.

Picard–Lindelöf in the multidimensional case along with continuous differentiability of $X$ lead to uniqueness of $\phi$.

Typical 'continuous dependence on initial conditions' results give continuity in $x_0$.